# How do I return two elements from a map function in the following code?

Tags: clojure

This is a follow on for another question I asked here for which I got an awesome answer. The premise is slightly modified from that question to allow this one.

How do I generate a table row with `:td`'s for both 'name' and 'value' as shown in this data structure:

```
(table-rows [{:name "foo" :value 1} {:name "hey" :value 2}])
```

starting with

```
(defn table-rows [data]
  (->> data
       (map (fn [{:keys [name] :as row}]
              [:td (:name row)]))
       (into [:tr])))
```

which returns at this point

```
=> [:tr [:td "foo"] [:td "hey"]]
```

The map `(fn...)` will only return the last element, right? And if I enclose the two `[:td]`'s in something, so that it is returned as a unit, the table would not work.

In my project I will have many more `[:td...]` elements than two; I chose two to simplify my question.

I suspect `let` is what I should be considering, but every time I start down that road I run into trouble so I thought I would ask.

UPDATE:

One question in the comments allowed me to realize this is what I'm looking for:

```
  (->> data
       (map (fn [{:keys [name] :as row}]
              [:tr
               [:td (:name row)]
               [:td (:value row)]]))
       (into [:tbody])))
```

which produces what I was after:

```
[:tbody [:tr [:td "foo"] [:td 1]] 
        [:tr [:td "hey"] [:td 2]]]
```

Thank you for the help!

UPDATE 2:

and I realize I can remove the destructuring from the argument to the 'fn' so that I have:

```
(defn table-rows [data]
  (->> data
       (map (fn [row]
              [:tr
               [:td (:name row)]
               [:td (:value row)]]))
       (into [:tbody])))
```

Comment: What should the output of calling `(table-rows [{:name "foo" :value 1} {:name "hey" :value 2}])` be?

Comment: I would want 
[:tr [:td "foo"][:td 1]]
[:tr [:td "hey"][:td 2]]

but your question is helping to realize 1. how confused I am and 2. that I need to be making [:tr]'s and putting them into a [:tbody]... let me try that and report back on how it goes.

Comment: And... your question got me unstuck. I'll update my question.

Comment: Nice, your solution looks good. But you can simplify the argument list `{:keys [name] :as row}` to just `row`.

Comment: Haha! I just spotted that and had updated my original question and then saw your comment... and thank you!

Comment: Just one thing: I would suggest that you post an answer to your own question and accept the answer, so that other people don't think it is unanswered :-)

Comment: It looks like I have to wait two days before accepting my own answer (unless you know a way for me accept it sooner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some wonderful help in the comments below, I was able to work out what I needed, which is:

```
(defn table-rows [data]
  (->> data
       (map (fn [row]
              [:tr
               [:td (:name row)]
               [:td (:value row)]]))
       (into [:tbody])))
```

which produces

```
[:tbody [:tr [:td "foo"] [:td 1]] 
        [:tr [:td "hey"] [:td 2]]]
```

Thanks you for the help!

(note to self: make sure to work out what I am trying to get from a function before posting here)

PS - it looks like I have to wait a few days to accept my own answer, which it was suggested I do so that this doesn't appear unanswered.